# Lambda writing CSV records into Dynamo Table does not completely write all records to that table

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have written a python Lambda module that uses a manifest for writing csv file records to the Dynamo table.

1. An external SA integration loads both the manifest file and the CSV files into an S3 bucket (The csv file names and their record sizes are written within the manifest file).
2. Then, a transfer lambda examines the S3 bucket's contents and uses Dynamo auto-scaling for times when several files are included with the manifest and each of those files could have a max of 100K records each (but the record sizes and number of files in the manifest could vary).
3. The transfer lambda calls a second lambda to load the records of those csv files, located within the manifest, into a dynamo table. This is the lambda that is causing the issue.

***However***, when I perform a sample test where the manifest contains only 1 csv file containing only 10 records, the dynamo table *inputs only inputs 2 records*

> H**ere is the Key index used as well as the Read and Write capacity plus the Projected Attributes**
> [image]

.

> **Here is the manifest containing the CSV file of 10 records.**
> [image]
>
> **Here is the integration code that loads the records of the manifest's CSV file , into the Dynamo Table.**

```
try:
    # get the object
    response = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('latin-1').split('\n')
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in csv.DictReader(response, delimiter=','):
            output_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            # batch_items = [];
            # batch_update_items = [];
            # batch_update_data = [];
            #print('<< ROW  >> ',row)
            #HANDLE EXTRANEOUS UNICODE CHARACTERS
            output_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            record = {}
            serviceAddress = {}
            householdInfo = {}
            if row['cac_addr_zip'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                zip = str(''.join(str(row['cac_addr_zip']).split('.')[0]))
                serviceAddress['zip'] = str(zip).zfill(5)
                #print('<<zip>> ', serviceAddress['zip'])
            if row['cac_addr_full'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                serviceAddress['address'] = str(row['cac_addr_full'])
                #print('<<address>> ', serviceAddress['address'])
            if row['mKey5'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                record['mKey5'] = str(row['mKey5'])

                #print('<<mKey5>> ', dyRecord['mKey5'])

            if row['cac_addr_city'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                serviceAddress['city'] = str(row['cac_addr_city'])
                #print('<<city>> ',serviceAddress['city'])

            
            if row['cac_addr_state'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                serviceAddress['state'] = str(row['cac_addr_state'])
                #print('<<state>> ',serviceAddress['state'])

            if row['cac_hh_built_year'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_hh_built_year'] = str(row['cac_hh_built_year'])
                #print('<<cac_hh_built_year>> ',householdInfo['cac_hh_built_year'] )
               
            if row['cac_home_sq_foot_num'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_home_sq_foot_num'] = str(row['cac_home_sq_foot_num'])
                #print('<<cac_home_sq_foot_num>> ',dyRecord['cac_home_sq_foot_num'])
                
            if row['cac_demo_num_in_hh'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_demo_num_in_hh'] = str(row['cac_demo_num_in_hh'])
                #print('<<cac_demo_num_in_hh>> ',row['cac_demo_num_in_hh'])
               
            if row['cac_demo_num_adults'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_demo_num_adults'] = str(row['cac_demo_num_adults'])
                #print('<<cac_demo_num_adults>> ',row['cac_demo_num_adults'])

            if row['cac_demo_hoh_age'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_demo_hoh_age'] = str(row['cac_demo_hoh_age'])
                #print('<<cac_demo_hoh_age>> ',row['cac_demo_hoh_age'])

            if row['cac_hh_home_own'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_hh_home_own'] = str(row['cac_hh_home_own'])
                #print('<<cac_hh_home_own>> ',row['cac_hh_home_own'])
                
            if row['cac_demo_num_kids'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_demo_num_kids'] = str(row['cac_demo_num_kids'])
                #print('<<cac_demo_num_kids>> ',row['cac_demo_num_kids'])
               
            if row['cac_demo_income'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_demo_income'] = str(row['cac_demo_income'])
                #print('<<cac_demo_income>> ',row['cac_demo_income'])
               
            if row['cac_int_112'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['cac_int_112'] = str(row['cac_int_112'])
                #print('<<cac_int_112>> ',row['cac_int_112'])
              
            if row['cac_silh_super'] not in (' ', '\\N') :
                householdInfo['cac_silh_super'] = str(row['cac_silh_super'])
                #print('<<cac_silh_super>> ',row['cac_silh_super'])
               
            if row['lifedriver_class'] not in (' ', '\\N') :
                householdInfo['lifedriver_class'] = str(row['lifedriver_class'])
                #print('<<lifedriver_class>> ',row['lifedriver_class'])
                
            if row['CAC_HH_AIRCONDITIONING'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['CAC_HH_AIRCONDITIONING'] = str(row['CAC_HH_AIRCONDITIONING'])
                #print('<<CAC_HH_AIRCONDITIONING>> ',row['CAC_HH_AIRCONDITIONING'])
              
            if row['CAC_HH_HOMEHEATINDICATOR'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['CAC_HH_HOMEHEATINDICATOR'] = str(row['CAC_HH_HOMEHEATINDICATOR'])
                #print('<<CAC_HH_HOMEHEATINDICATOR>> ',row['CAC_HH_HOMEHEATINDICATOR'])
               
            if row['CAC_HH_RES_LENGTH'] not in (' ', '\\N'):
                householdInfo['CAC_HH_RES_LENGTH'] = str(row['CAC_HH_RES_LENGTH'])
                #print('<<CAC_HH_RES_LENGTH>> ',row['CAC_HH_RES_LENGTH'])
                
            record['lastModifiedDate'] = output_date
           
            # INSERTING NEW RECORDS    
            record['serviceAddress'] = serviceAddress
            record['householdInfo'] = householdInfo
            print('<< RECORDS FOR FILE NAME >> ',file_name,record)
            table.put_item(Item=record)
            count += 1
            # print(count)
                
except Exception as e:
    message = "Process Failed, count = {count} and reason: ".format(count = count)
    print(message,e)
```

> **Here is the lambda's log file which shows that 10 records have been written to the dynamo table.**
> [image]

> **Finally, here is the dynamo table with only 2 records.Thanks**
> [image]

Comment: PutItem will replace an existing item if you indicate a duplicate primary key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` as the partition key for your items. That causes all your items to overwrite one another. In DynamoDB your partition key must be unique or your partition and sort key if one is defined.

Make sure you have a unique primary key for each and every item in the base table.

Comment: I wanted my unique primary key to be the mKey5 but it is used as an index.

Comment: If mKey5 is unique, then make it your base table partition key. Index on non-unique keys.

Comment: OK Thanks. Do you know if I can change my partition key with out having to delete the entire table in AWS? . mKey5 is based on the joining of the address (where entity abbreviations and location abbreviations are removed) and joined with zip code.  This should be unique enough otherwise I will go with a randomizer.

Comment: Unfortunately to change a partition key you will have to delete the table, and/or create a new one.

Comment: Ok Thanks Leeroy this worked Great. I added mKey5  as the  partition key and then I added an index key called prospectNumber which combined the python  urandom() function value (15 hex characters in length) appended to  the mKey5 key. I did take a while for the 10 records to generate and display in the Table but it worked. I got all of my 10 records listed.